# Instantiating ParticleSystem with getting/setting particles

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Could someone please help me understand what I am doing wrong that I get `NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object` errors?

This is taken from an old tutorial that originally does not instantiate the `ParticleSystem`, so based on the answers to a similar post, I have amended it to work, but it seems like it still does not instantiate...

Initially, it had only used `particleSystem.SetParticles(points, points.Length);` in the `Update` method, but that did not work, and searching for the answer led me to a dedicated post to this issue, but the suggested solutions still do not make it work.

What am I doing wrong here?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Grapher1 : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int _resolution = 10;
    private ParticleSystem.Particle[] _points;
    private ParticleSystem _particleSystem;


    private void Start()
    {
        if (_resolution < 10 || _resolution > 100)
        {
            Debug.LogWarning("Grapher resolution out of bounds, resetting to minimum 10", this);
            _resolution = 10;
        }

        _points = new ParticleSystem.Particle[_resolution];
        _particleSystem.Emit(_resolution);
        _particleSystem.GetParticles(_points);

        float increment = 1f / (_resolution - 1);
        for (int i = 0; i < _resolution; i++)
        {
            float x = i * increment;
            _points[i].position = new Vector3(x, 0f, 0f);
            _points[i].color = new Color(x, 0f, 0f);
            _points[i].size = 0.1f;
        }
    }


    private void Update()
    {
        _particleSystem.SetParticles(_points, _points.Length);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you assigning a valid object to `_particleSystem`?

Comment: Double click on the error in the Editor and it will show you the line of code that is causing that error. Tell us what that line of code looks like.

Comment: @UnholySheep I create a private instance and then use the available public method with the dot operator. Is this not sufficient?

Comment: Where in this code are you creating a private instance? `private ParticleSystem _particleSystem;` only declares a (reference) variable, it does not create an instance (also you shouldn't be creating `ParticleSystem`s programmatically - instead it should be attached via the editor to the game object and then retrieved using `GetComponent`)

Comment: @Programmer After putting in both `Emit` and `Get`, the error is pointed to this line: `_particleSystem.Emit(_resolution);` By the way, the game object to which this script is attached is an empty game object with a particle system component attached to it...

Comment: @UnholySheep Thank you! I added `_particleSystem = GetComponent<ParticleSystem>();` and removed both `Emit` and `GetParticles`, and it is working now. If you could move your comments to the answer section, I will imeediately mark it as answer. Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Initialize `_particleSystem`.  Add _particleSystem = GetComponent<ParticleSystem>()` to the top of the `Start` function. Also, make sure that `ParticleSystem`  is attached to the-same GameObject `Grapher1` script is attached to. EDIT: Ok, You got it fixed. This is a duplicate but I will let UnholySheep add answer if he wants.

Comment: @Programmer Thank you very much. I was missing that part. I thought a particle system being added as a component would just work...

Comment: No. You use AddComponent to do that from script.

Comment: @Programmer Got it.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments:

```
private ParticleSystem _particleSystem;
```

only declares a (reference) variable, it does not create an instance.

The preferred way of using a `ParticleSystem` is to attach it to the game object and then referencing it via `GetComponent`, in this case by adding

```
_particleSystem = GetComponent<ParticleSystem>();
```

in the `Start()` method.

Another option is to programmatically add a component to the gameobject via [`GameObject.AddComponent`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.AddComponent.html), however it is usually preferable to attach components directly via the editor (as `AddComponent` adds runtime overhead)